# Auto populate a form using a mapping object and a flow

Tags: visual-workflow, object-relational-mapping

We have a form that users assign by selecting from two picklists, one for the assignees name and one for their email.

We're wanting to simplify this for the end user by using a combination of a mapping object and a flow.

The mapping object will consist of a user lookup field, and it will have 1:1 associated assignee and email address.

The idea would be for a flow to get records from the mapping object, check who is logged, locate the record that contains the mapping of the person logged in, then when the user creates the form, it should auto-populate the name and email fields on the custom form, I do not know if it's possible to have it prefill in any of the fields prior to saving?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to do this by following these steps:

Create a Mapping Object:

Create a custom object that will act as a mapping object. This object should have two fields: a lookup field (to store the assignment) for each User object and a text field (or email field) to store an associated email address.
Create a flow:

Create a flow in Salesforce that consists of the following steps:

a. Get the current logged in user information.

b. Query the mapping object and find the record that matches the logged in user.

c. Store the received and assigned email address in a variable.

d. Present a form to the user, first filling in the name and email fields with values ​​from the mapping object.
To add the flow to your custom form:

Depending on your application scenario, you can combine flows in different ways in your own customized way. For example, you can create a custom button or link that triggers a flow and opens a form with pre-populated fields.
Just create the name and email fields:

When the flow presents a form to the user, you can pre-populate the corresponding fields on the form with variables that store the recruiter’s name and email.

Save form data:

When the user submits the form, process the data as needed (e.g., store in a custom container, send an email notification, etc.).